# How big is too big (for NTFS)

Tags: ntfs, limits, design-consideration

I have a program and as it's done now, it has a data directory with something like 10-30K files in it and it's starting to cause problems. Should I *expect* that to cause problems and my only solution to tweak my file structure or does that indicate other problems?

Comment: @BCSD Did my answer, answer your question? if so could you please accept. thanks

Comment: @Vecdid, It looks like it's the best I'm going to get...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[A related Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197162/ntfs-performance-and-large-volumes-of-files-and-directories)

[Optimize NTFS hard disk performance in Windows servers](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5034399.html)

[How to Optimize NTFS Performance](http://www.ehow.com/how_5713047_optimize-ntfs-performance.html)

When Windows NT, 2000 or XP accesses a directory on an NTFS volume, it updates the LastAccess time stamp on each directory it detects. Therefore, if there are a large number of directories, this can affect performance.

[This tweak disables this time stamp update](http://www.regxplor.com/tweak23.html)

Comment: That last bit is good to know as one "fix" (in effect, sharding) would result in large numbers of directories (as opposed to the current, huge numbers of just files). From your point, my fix might be even worse.

Comment: The link gives no citation or context for that claim. I strongly suspect it means that each subdirectory is accessed [and therefore last access date is updated] when the directory _is opened in Explorer_, not when it is accessed by any process