# What is better for performance - many files in one directory, or many subdirectories each with one file?

Tags: file, filesystems

While building web applications often we have files associated with database entries, eg: we have a `user` table and each category has a `avatar` field, which holds the path to associated image.

To make sure there are no conflicts in filenames we can either:

- rename files upon upload to `ID.jpg`; the path would be then `/user-avatars/ID.jpg`
- or create a sub-directory for each entity, and leave the original filename intact; the path would be then `/user-avatars/ID/original_filename.jpg`

where ID is `users`'s unique ID number

Both perfectly valid from application logic's point of view.

But which one would be better from filesystem performance point of view? We have to keep in mind that the number of `category` entries can be very high (milions).

Is there any limit to a number of sub-directories a directory can hold?

Comment: That depends on the filesystem.

Comment: For small mostly read-only files (like avatar pictures) which do not change often, using a dedicated DB *may* make sense. Even a local SQLite3 instance could be worth it. See https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html - But in a web server context, static files resources makes more sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's going to depend on your file system, but I'm going to assume you're talking about something simple like ext3, and you're not running a distributed file system (some of which are quite good at this).  In general, file systems perform poorly over a certain number of entries in a single directory, regardless of whether those entries are directories or files.   So no matter whether if you're creating one directory per image or one image in the root directory, you will run into scaling problems.  If you look at this answer:

[How many files in a directory is too many (on Windows and Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994544/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many-on-windows-and-linux?rq=1)

You'll see that ext3 runs into limits at about 32K entries in a directory, far fewer than you're proposing.

Off the top of my head, I'd suggest doing some rudimentary sharding into a multilevel directory tree, something like /user-avatars/1/2/12345/original_filename.jpg.  (Or something appropriate for your type of ID, but I am interpreting your question to be about numeric IDs.)  Doing that will also make your life easier later when you decide you want to distribute across a storage cluster, since you can spread the directories around.

Comment: I've read that SO, but I didn't know that that limit applies also to subdirectories. And yes, I'm asking about basic filesystems (windows/ntfs or linux/ext3).

Comment: I can also add, based on experiences in super-computing, that even if your file system will support a million files in a directory (and some will), your performance degrades pretty sharply for even basic operations. Many are linear in the size of the dir.  Something like an ls requires a few system calls per entry (get the file name, stat the file, check the security xattrs)...  Multiply that by a million, and you have a serious bottleneck.  It can take hours to return.

Comment: So, with a numeric ID, if I use the solution you suggested and save the file in, eg. `/12/34/56/my_file.jpg` (for each  2 digits in the ID, a new subdirectory) which would limit the number of sub-directories in each directory to a maximum of 100 (0-99)... will that be enough to get a decent performance?

Comment: That'll work...  I'd go for a slightly wider branching factor, say 123/456/ for a thousand files per dir.  That'll mean a max depth between two and three (log base 1K of 10M), while still being very manageable for the file system, and still fairly human readable, should, god forbid, you need to actually look at the contents.

Answer (score 4):

Millions of entries (either files or directories) in one parent directory would be hard to deal with for any filesystem. While modern filesystems use sorting and various tree algorithms for quick search for the needed files, even navigating to the folder with Windows Explorer or Midnight Commander or any other file manager will be complicated as the file manager would have to read contents of the directory. The same applies to file search. So subdirectories are preferred for this.

Yet I need to notice that access to particular file would be a bit faster when all files are in one directory than when they are separated into subdirectories at least on NTFS (measured this myself several times with 400K files).

Answer (score 3):

I've been having a very similar issue with html files not images. Trying to store millions of them in a Ubuntu server in ext4. Ended running my own benchmarks. Found out that flat directory performs way better while being way simpler to use:

[image: benchmark]

Reference: [article](https://medium.com/@hartator/benchmark-deep-directory-structure-vs-flat-directory-structure-to-store-millions-of-files-on-ext4-cac1000ca28)

Comment: How many files is there? I don't think this is conclusive without that info.

Comment: The article indicates 10 million files.

Comment: The referenced article was edited and changed its conclusion: *"Conclusion 2: stick to custom wisdom and use a deep directory file system. However, be wary of the performance cost of too many directory levels."*

Comment: Doesn't his test include the time it takes to access the substrings of his filename? What if i just store the full path in the db? I wonder is there any performance difference in accessing files in the same folder vs sub dirs..

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use files, maybe your best bet is to partition the files off into several subdirectories so that you don't hit a limit. For example, if you have an ID 123456, you can put it in /12/34/56.jpg.

However, I would recommend just using the database to store this data since you are already using one.  You can store the image data and ID in the same table, and you don't have to worry about some of the pesky business of dealing with files like making sure the permissions are set right, etc.

Comment: Not all databases perform well when storing nontrivially- (and variably-)sized binary blobs. Wouldn't outrightly recommend this, not without benchmarking.

Comment: @FrankH. You make a good point. I guess that will also depend on the context of the application.