# Writing on existing files in a filesystem database

Tags: php, database, file, database-design, filesystems

I have a function that writes ~120Kb-150Kb HTML and meta data on ~8000 `.md` files with fixed names every few minutes:

```
a-agilent-technologies-healthcare-nyse-us-39d4
aa-alcoa-basic-materials-nyse-us-159a
aaau-perth-mint-physical-gold--nyse-us-8ed9
aaba-altaba-financial-services-nasdaq-us-26f5
aac-healthcare-nyse-us-e92a
aadr-advisorshares-dorsey-wright-adr--nyse-us-d842
aal-airlines-industrials-nasdaq-us-29eb
```

- If file does not exist, it generates/writes quite fast.
- If however the file exists, it does the same much slower, since the existing file carries ~150KB data.

---

How do I solve this problem?

Do I generate a new file with a new name in the same directory, and unlink the older file in the `for` loop?

or do I generate a new folder and write all files then I unlink the previous directory? The problem with this method is that sometimes 90% of files are being rewritten and some remain the same.

---

#### Code

This function is being called in a `for` loop, which you can see it in this [link](https://github.com/emarcier/usco/blob/master/master/cron/equity/EQ.php)

```
public static function writeFinalStringOnDatabase($equity_symbol, $md_file_content, $no_extension_filename)
{
    /**
     *@var is the MD file content with meta and entire HTML
     */
    $md_file_content = $md_file_content . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE;
    $dir = __DIR__ . ConfigConstants::DIR_FRONT_SYMBOLS_MD_FILES; // symbols front directory
    $new_filename = EQ::generateFileNameFromLeadingURL($no_extension_filename, $dir);

    if (file_exists($new_filename)) {
        if (is_writable($new_filename)) {
            file_put_contents($new_filename, $md_file_content);
            if (EQ::isLocalServer()) {
                echo $equity_symbol . "  " . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE;
            }

        } else {
            if (EQ::isLocalServer()) {
                echo $equity_symbol . " symbol MD file is not writable in " . __METHOD__ . "  Maybe, check permissions!" . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $fh = fopen($new_filename, 'wb');
        fwrite($fh, $md_file_content);
        fclose($fh);
        if (EQ::isLocalServer()) {
            echo $equity_symbol . " front md file does not exit in " . __METHOD__ . " It's writing on the database now " . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you use `file_put_contents` and `fwrite` if they act the same? Or let me put it this way: Why do you have the `if (file_exists($new_filename))` at all?

Comment: If you're generating the (mostly) same 8000 files every few minutes, it seems to me that the better solution would be to generate them on the fly as they're requested. (Or are they not requested via the web?)

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea in Total as disk partitions can slow down then many files exists in one directory see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994544/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many-on-windows-and-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't programmed in PHP for years, but this question has drawn my interest today. :D

**Suggestion**

> How do I solve this problem?
>     Do I generate a new file with a new name in the same directory, and unlink the older file in the for loop?

Simply use the 3 amigos `fopen()`, `fwrite()` & `fclose()` again, since `fwrite` will also overwrite the entire content of an existing file.

```php
if (file_exists($new_filename)) {
    if (is_writable($new_filename)) {
        $fh = fopen($new_filename,'wb');
        fwrite($fh, $md_file_content);
        fclose($fh);

        if (EQ::isLocalServer()) {
            echo $equity_symbol . "  " . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE;
        }
    } else {
        if (EQ::isLocalServer()) {
            echo $equity_symbol . " symbol MD file is not writable in " . __METHOD__ . "  Maybe, check permissions!" . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE;
        }
    }
} else {
    $fh = fopen($new_filename, 'wb');
    fwrite($fh, $md_file_content);
    fclose($fh);
    if (EQ::isLocalServer()) {
        echo $equity_symbol . " front md file does not exit in " . __METHOD__ . " It's writing on the database now " . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE;
    }
}
```

For the sake of *DRY* principle:

```php
// It's smart to put the logging and similar tasks in a separate function, 
// after you end up writing the same thing over and over again.
public static function log($content)
{
    if (EQ::isLocalServer()) {
        echo $content;
    }
}

public static function writeFinalStringOnDatabase($equity_symbol, $md_file_content, $no_extension_filename)
{
    $md_file_content = $md_file_content . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE;
    $dir = __DIR__ . ConfigConstants::DIR_FRONT_SYMBOLS_MD_FILES; // symbols front directory
    $new_filename = EQ::generateFileNameFromLeadingURL($no_extension_filename, $dir);
    $file_already_exists = file_exists($new_filename);

    if ($file_already_exists && !is_writable($new_filename)) {
        EQ::log($equity_symbol . " symbol MD file is not writable in " . __METHOD__ . "  Maybe, check permissions!" . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE);
    } else {
        $fh = fopen($new_filename,'wb'); // you should also check whether fopen succeeded
        fwrite($fh, $md_file_content); // you should also check whether fwrite succeeded

        if ($file_already_exists) {
            EQ::log($equity_symbol . "  " . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE);
        } else {
            EQ::log($equity_symbol . " front md file does not exit in " . __METHOD__ . " It's writing on the database now " . ConfigConstants::NEW_LINE);
        }

        fclose($fh);
    }
}
```

---

**Possible cause**

**tl;dr** To much overhead due to [the Zend string API](https://phpinternals.net/categories/zend_strings) being used.

The official [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) says:

> `file_put_contents()` is identical to calling `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` successively to write data to a file.

However, if you look at the [source code of PHP on GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src), you can see that the part "writing data" is done slightly different in `file_put_contents()` and `fwrite()`.

- In the `fwrite` function the raw input data (= `$md_file_content`) is directly accessed in order to write the buffer data to the stream context:

  [Line 1171](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L1171):

```cpp
ret = php_stream_write(stream, input, num_bytes);
```

- In the `file_put_contents` function on the other hand [the Zend string API](https://phpinternals.net/categories/zend_strings) is used (which I never heard before).
  Here the input data and length is encapsulated for some reason.

  [Line 662](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L662)

```cpp
numbytes = php_stream_write(stream, Z_STRVAL_P(data), Z_STRLEN_P(data));
```

(The `Z_STR....` macros are defined [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h), if you are interested).

So, my suspicion is that possibly the *Zend string API* is causing the overhead while using `file_put_contents`.

---

**side note**

At first I thought that every `file_put_contents()` call creates a new stream context, since the lines related to creating context were also slightly different:

`PHP_NAMED_FUNCTION(php_if_fopen)` ([Reference](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L875)):

```
context = php_stream_context_from_zval(zcontext, 0);
```

`PHP_FUNCTION(file_put_contents)` ([Reference](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L608)):

```
context = php_stream_context_from_zval(zcontext, flags & PHP_FILE_NO_DEFAULT_CONTEXT);
```

However, on closer inspection, the [php_stream_context_from_zval](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/php_stream_context.h#L33) call is made effectively with the same params, that is the first param `zcontext` is `null`, and since you don't pass any `flags` to `file_put_contents`, `flags & PHP_FILE_NO_DEFAULT_CONTEXT` becomes also `0` and is passed as second param.

So, I guess the [default stream context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-get-default.php) is re-used here on every call. Since it's apparently a stream of type `persistent` it is not disposed after the [php_stream_close()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L711) call. 
So the *Fazit*, as the Germans say, is there is apparently either no additional overhead or equally same overhead regarding the creation or reusing a stream context in both cases.

Thank you for reading.