# Can having many files in a folder affect performances?

Tags: windows, performance, macos, file, directory

I've got an application that's going to generate about 20,000 files. To keep it simple, I'm thinking about putting all these files in the same folder. Am I likely to run into some performance issues doing so? My software is for Windows XP, Vista, Seven and Mac OS X.

Any idea?

Comment: My guess is no, it won't be any slower than 20k files in different folder. Unless, if that folder happens to be your desktop or an open window. (I've done this before - accidentally set WinRar to a partition size of 100 instead of 100MB. On my desktop...)

Comment: This thread is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197162/ntfs-performance-and-large-volumes-of-files-and-directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that Doxygen has a feature to break the generated files up into multiple directories because of slowness in access files in large directories under Windows.  I don't know if this is just FAT or NTFS or both.