# Does ReFS handle small files and large deletes faster than NTFS?

Tags: performance, filesystems, ntfs, refs

I work with developer tools like git and npm/yarn that often generate lots of small files.

I know from [NTFS performance and large volumes of files and directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197162/ntfs-performance-and-large-volumes-of-files-and-directories) (and from experience) that NTFS doesn't handle these as fast as most Unix filesystems.

However I also know never versions of Windows support ReFS, a new Microsoft filesystem.

My question is: **does ReFS handle small files and large deletes faster than NTFS?**

Comment: The only obvious performance data on the matter doesn't look hugely promising: https://www.flexense.com/server_2016_refs_file_system_performance.html