# PowerShell Delete more quickly

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that recursively deletes all files and folders, but excludes certain folders as they should not be deleted. 
It works 100%, but my problem is performance. I need this to run a lot faster.

Any ideas on how to make this faster?

```
Write-Host "Purging $InstallationDirectorySite - Deleting files..."

$FolderExlusions = (
    "App_Data",
    "Logs",
    "TEMP",
    "ExamineIndexes",
    "DistCache",
    "GitPathProviderRepository"
)

[regex] $files_regex = "Logs|ExamineIndexes|DistCache*|GitPathProviderRepository*"

if(Test-Path $InstallationDirectorySite) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $InstallationDirectorySite -Recurse -Exclude $FolderExlusions |
        Where-Object {$_.FullName -notmatch $files_regex} |
        Remove-Item -Recurse
}
else {
    Write-Output "$InstallationDirectorySite doesn't exist"
}
```

Comment: You could compare the speed of com or .net methods instead of `rm -r`: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/14089f8a-65eb-4c31-8d87-2485963bda2b/quickly-delete-large-folders-with-ps?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Consider using intermediate variables instead of piping. Combine that with `Measure-Command` to find out which part, exactly, is the slow one. How slow is the delete now and what kind of performance are you looking for? How many directories and files are you working with?

Comment: The delete has to process 40 odd folders, but those folders contain a lot of files. The worst folder is the node modules folder that contains a ton of files.
The delete at the moment is around 2 minutes, if I can halve that I would be happy.

I will definitely look into Measure-Command for some testing

Comment: NTFS is known to have its quirks with large number of files. See [earlier a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197162). TL;DR: disable 8.3 file names and last access time for 1000+ files / dir environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in fact filtering the excluded folders twice.
The first time using the `-Exclude` parameter and the second time using a Regex `-match`.
However, the `Exclude` parameter takes a string array, not a single string with keywords separated by a comma and a newline as you get from the 'here-string'.
See [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6)

Also, the regex you use is wrong, because the asteriks `*` in regex is a quantifier, not a wildcard character.

I suggest you filter once using either the `-Exclude` parameter like this (here the asteriks is a Wildcard):

```
$FolderExlusions = "App_Data","Logs","TEMP","ExamineIndexes","DistCache*","GitPathProviderRepository*"
Get-ChildItem -Path $InstallationDirectorySite -Recurse -Exclude $FolderExlusions | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

Or use only the regex method in a `Where-Object` clause like this:

```
$FolderExlusions = "^(App_Data|Logs|TEMP|ExamineIndexes|DistCache.*|GitPathProviderRepository.*)"
Get-ChildItem -Path $InstallationDirectorySite -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch $FolderExlusions } | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` if you are satisfied with the results.

Hope that helps

Comment: I have been testing and the  Where-Object {$_.FullName -notmatch $files_regex} actually works and stops the exclusion from deleting the folder and it's children.
Without it the folder is not deleted, but the children are, which is not the result we want as we want to keep the folder and it's children.

Does not look like I will get much gain either way. Time to move to SSD on servers then,