# How to speed up Get-ChildItem in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Just wandering how could I speed up the Get-ChildItem in Powershell?

I have the following script to search for a file that created by today and copy it over to another folder.

```
$fromDirectory = "test_file_*.txt"
$fromDirectory = "c:\sour\"
$toDirectory = "c:\test\"

Get-ChildItem $fromDirectory -Include $fileName -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).Date} | Copy-Item -Destination $toDirectory
```

Due to the folder that I search have 124,553 history files, it's take me age for the search. Does any know how could I improve my script to speed up my search and copy?

Comment: this is a classic use case for `robocopy`. [*grin*] it is FAST and has options to get files by date range. it will often be an order of magnitude faster than `G-CI` since the 2nd of those adds lots [and lots and lots] of meta data to every file object.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things to try:

First, use Measure-Command {} to get the actual performance:

```
Measure-Command { Get-ChildItem $fromDirectory -Include $fileName -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).Date} | Copy-Item -Destination $toDirectory }
```

Then, consider removing the '-Recurse' flag, because this is actually going inside every directory and child and child of child.  If your target log files are really that scattered, then...

Try using robocopy to match a pattern in the filename and lastwritetime, then use powershell to copy over.  You could even use robocopy to do the copying.

It's possible that you just have a huge, slow problem to solve, but try these to see if you can break it down.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known feature of NTFS. Microsoft's [docs say](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2539403/system-may-pause-while-accessing-large-ntfs-folder) that the limit for decreasing performance is about 50 000 files in a directory.

If the file names are of very similar, creation of 8dot3 legacy names will start to slow down when there are [about 300 000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc781134(v=ws.10)) files. Though you have "only" 120 k files, it's the same order of magnitude.

Some [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197162/503046) discuss [this issue](https://serverfault.com/q/768755/85798). Sadly, there is no a single good solution but better hierarchy in directories. The usual tricks are to disable 8dot3 with `fsutil` and last access date via registry, but those will help only so much.

Can you redesign the directory structure? Moving old files into, say, year-quarter subdirs might keep the main directory clean enough. To find out file's year-quarter, a quick way is like so,

```
gci | % { 
  $("{2} => {1}\Q{0:00}" -f [Math]::ceiling( ($_.LastAccessTime.toString('MM'))/3),
    $_.LastAccessTime.ToString('yyyy'), 
    $_.Name 
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting the `Get-ChildItem $fromDirectory -Include $fileName -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).Date}` in an Array and then copying results from the Array.

```
$GrabFiles =@()
$GrabFiles =@( Get-ChildItem $fromDirectory -Include $fileName -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).Date} )
Copy-Item -Path $GrabFiles -Destination $toDirectory }
```