# golang copy files takes too much time

Tags: windows, macos, file, go

I use the following code to copy files which works OK
The problem is that when we use this method to copy folder and items like node_js project with node_modules inside
in **windows** this can take a long time about **40 sec** and in mac it takes **2 sec**.
when doing trace (print the copied files) we saw that for example the `io.copy` took 5 sec to copy short readme file
or json file , in each run it get s**tuck on different files** , small size files like json readme etch
this is **not consistent**, in **different run** it stuck on **different files** ( if you run on same project).

we checked it on 3 different windows10  machine ( 1-3 years old) and 2 different macbook (3 years old)
on **exact same project**. What it can be ?

```
func walk(src string, baseDir string, archive *zip.Writer) error {
   return filepath.Walk(src, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) (e error) {
      if err != nil {
         return err
      }

      if info.IsDir() {
         return
      }

      header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
      if err != nil {
         return err
      }
      if baseDir != "" {
         header.Name = filepath.ToSlash(getRelativePath(path, baseDir))
      }

      header.Method = zip.Deflate
      writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
      if err != nil {
         return err
      }

      file, err := os.Open(path)
      if err != nil {
         return err
      }
      defer func() {
         e = CloseFile(file, e)
      }()

      _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
      return err
   })
}
```

we are checking it almost 4 days and we didnt find any pattern :(

Comment: Can you use rsync instead of golang?

Comment: I know someone already told you this, but it's the OS. You can do a search about NTF + small files to confirm

Comment: @Ben - sorry what do you mean instead of golang ? can you provide example what to change ?

Comment: @yorodm - someone told me what ? :)

Comment: There's usually some *nix fan in every time that blames Windows for every bad thing in the Universe, I assumed there was one in your team. Nevertheless, NTFS has some issues when dealing with small files and there are a lot of those in a `node_modules` folder. That's the root of all your performance issues.

Comment: have you considered to parallelize the job ?

Comment: You should skip the node_modules folder. Just copy your files and then run `npm init`, that is much faster.

Comment: @mh-cbon a bad idea if your destination is not able to write prallel.

Comment: @NinaS there's a unix tool called `rsync` that copies files from one location to another, and on subsequent copies, it only copies the *changes* from the first location. Because of the nature of node_modules, you'd likely only pay the small file cost on the first copy (I haven't tested this). Unfortunately, I couldn't find a maintained open-source windows version in my quick Googling.

Comment: @apxp i don t understand your remark. he is copying file by file, why would it be unsafe ? tree traversal can be made twice to setup folders at first, then apply a second traversal to copy the files in //. what did you mean ?

Comment: With Windows file acesses you should be concerned about the effects of Windows Defender Antivirus and other antimalware programs. Does turning them off make any difference?

Comment: @yorodm why would it be the OS? have you tested the copying in another language like C++ or  .NET. I get very fast copy speeds in .NET, but not in golang. So maybe it's the way golang calls the windows API.

Comment: I've had the same issue, the solution was to create the file first, then do all the checks and then copy (write) the data.

Comment: @s952163 NTFS has performance issues with small files. `node_modules` has mostly small files. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845026/opening-many-small-files-on-ntfs-is-way-too-slow) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/768755/sluggish-performance-on-ntfs-drive-with-large-number-of-files)

Comment: As others have mentioned, it may indeed be the NFTS performance with small files. Did you try to zip and transfer all files as a sole unit? It should have performance comparable to the Mac one, otherwise some other networking issue could be the culprit.

Comment: @Dippo, were you writing into a zip file? I have this same problem right now, especially with a streaming response.

Comment: @Edwinner No, not a zip file.